# can I use visual studio 2013 with unity 5

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015

I have Windows 10 installed on my laptop and I want to know if can use Visual Studio 2013 with the latest unity 3-d software. Also unity installed a Visual Studio community 2015. Will that community software work as well?

Comment: Consider just using ordinary old Mono which comes with Unity.  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx has a huge amount of DATA GATHERING. avoid it.

Comment: hi @kishLankashire .. did the answer below answer your question?

Comment: Depending on which VS and Unity you are using; consider also using _Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity_ (formerly _UnityVS_) so that you can code and debug your code from VS with the output appearing in Unity. _[Apparently VSTU is now a part of Unity 5.2](http://unityvs.com/documentation/native-support/)_

Comment: Unclear why this was **put on hold** since it is an obvious **boolean** answer fully documented by Microsoft and Unity and in no way _"too broad"_

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use either: VS 2013 (any version) or VS-Community 2015.

Comment: i didn't realise they now include VisualStudio in the download? on pc I guess.

Comment: Yea. It's optional, if I remember right. They almost force everyone to re-download a second time, because they made all the basic build platforms optional too -_-''

Comment: right - that platform stuff is a nuisance.  I see, it's an option.  good one.

Comment: They didn't include visual studio but it's visual studio community. I just wanted to know if I can use visual studio(old one) with unity(latest one).

Comment: Yes, you can. But pay attention to Joe Blow's comment under your question.